# Selenium (chromedriver) in MAC

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, configuration, automation

I have the following problem/question:
I was with notebook automation. Now I bought an ultrabook MAC.

I did all the project import with automation, all right. However, when I run it, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /Users/estevaomarcos/Documents/Projetos/DBServer/\Users\chromedriver
```

In my code is the following:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "\\Users\\chromedriver");
WebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver(); .....
```

Answer (score 2):

**Set Driver Path:** To avoid manual checking for the operating system we can get the file separator symbol from the system property using the file.separator key.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Users" + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "chromedriver");
WebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver();
browser.get("test.com");
```

Setting driver path based on which **Operating System(OS)** we are running on.

```
String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            if(os.contains("mac")) { 
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("usr.home") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "chromedriver");
            }else {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("usr.home") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "chromedriver.exe");
            }
```

Comment: or just use "+File.separator+" for the slash

Comment: agree, we can also use System.getProperty("file.separator") to get current os file separator. Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: Guys, I did not understand. Sorry!  Could you detail it? 
Could you give an example with my code?

Comment: Replace system.setproperty with System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("usr.dir") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "chromedriver");

Comment: Didn't work. The error remains... =//     I used the following code:          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("usr.dir") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "chromedriver");
        WebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver();
        browser.get("http://www.test.com");    Do you have any more idea?

Comment: Hope now driver file is located and you are not getting previous error.

Comment: And now???     java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /Users/estevaomarcos/Documents/Projetos/DBServerTest/null/chromedriver

Comment: Please share where are you keeping chromedriver file. Please share the exact path.

Comment: See below!!     "\\Users\\chromedriver".   
The path bar is as follows (Finder): MAC>Usuarios>estevao>Documentos>chromedriver .    Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please see this,     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Users" + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "chromedriver");
    WebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver();
    browser.get("test.com");

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work... =// 
I tried but I did not succeed

Comment: At last !! System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Users" + File.separator + "chromedriver"); WebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver(); browser.get("test.com");

Comment: I m sorry i do not have mac with me.

Comment: if nothing works then you shall simply go for as of now System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "//Users//chromedriver");
WebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver();

Comment: it's "user.home", not "usr.home"... System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+... but be sure the chromedriver is placed in the current user's folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. In a code based on operating system you should initialise        new ChromeDriver after System.setProperty setup only.
2. user.home is correct option - NOT "usr"
   Finally it works(java) great when looks like this:

```js
String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
if (os.contains("mac")) {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.home") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "chromedriver");
} else {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.home") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "chromedriver.exe");
}
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```